# Logarithmic growth rates

Tags: logarithms

I  have this question in terms of grown rate (Computer Science Big-OH):

Rank the following three functions: $\log N$, $\log(N^2)$, $\log^2 N$. Explain.

I understand the first two are both $O(N)$ as $\log(N^2) = 2 \log (N)$.  I am hoping someone can help explain to me what happens when you square a log.  I am assuming this one will have the least growth rate?  Also can someone mention on how to use the superscript so i don't have to use the carrot?

Comment: By $\log^2 N$ do you mean $(\log N)^2$ or $\log (\log N)$?

Comment: You can see my edit for how I formatted the mathematical notation. In general you wrap any expression by "$\$\cdots\$$" and format with the mathJax syntax as described in the 'help' documentation

Comment: ok thanks,  I mean $(log N)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, $\log(N^2) = 2\log(N)$ and therefore $\log(N^2) \in O(\log(N))$.

Asymptotically, both grow slower than $\log(N)^2$, i.e. $\log(N) \in o(\log(N)^2)$.

Proof: For every positive constant $c > 0$, there needs to exists an $N^*$, such that
\begin{equation}
c \log(N) < \log(N)^2.
\end{equation}
for every $N \ge N^*$.
As we can choose $N^* > 1$, $\log(N^*)$ is positive and monotonously increasing. Thus we can divide by $\log(N^*)$ to get:
\begin{equation}
c < \log(N^*).
\end{equation}
From this we can solve for $N^*$ using whatever base of the logarithm we agreed upon. Therefore, an appropriate $N^*$ exists and the statement follows.

Comment: Thanks for breaking it out.  dumb question but what exactly does the e symbol mean?

Comment: Which e symbol?
If you mean $\in$, that is set membership. For example  $1 \in \mathbb N$ means 1 is in the set of natural numbers. $f \in O(g)$ means that $f$ belongs to the set of functions that asymptotically grow no faster than $g$ (times a constant factor).